# Databricks - Run create replace view in python console

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

have creted a datframe abc can i run a sql query like this if not how,im not so gud at python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwTBa.png)

Query="diff" colmnval="456" if query == "diff": abc.createorReplaceTempView("XY_stg") else abc.createorReplaceTempView("XY_stg") CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW XY_stg as select *,'' as newperf from XY_stg where column={colmnval}

this is the code in trying to exute in databricks notebook it inculdes both ptyhon variables and sql statement of creation the view based on condition

Comment: Please provide some more details about your question. What does your code look like (include actual code, not pictures). What have you tried, where are you stuck? If you receive any error messages those can also be helpful in answering your question.

Comment: query="diff"
colmnval="456"
if query == "diff":
abc.createorReplaceTempView("XY_stg")
else 
abc.createorReplaceTempView("XY_stg")
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW XY_stg as
select *,'' as newperf from XY_stg where column={colmnval}

Comment: this is the code in trying to exute in databricks notebook it inculdes both ptyhon variables and sql statement of creation the view based on condition

Comment: Please update your question with the additional information using the 'edit' button. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Regarding your problem, it looks like you're mixing SQL and python in a single cell. Use one or the other, not both. By having `%sql` or `%python` as the first line of your cell you can switch between the two, see https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-use.html#mix-languages

Comment: @malcolmrichard, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may follow below steps to create replace view in python console.

> You can override the default language by specifying the language magic command **`%<language>`** at the beginning of a cell. The supported magic commands are: **`%python`**, **`%r`**, **`%scala`**, and **`%sql`**.

**Step1:** Creating a Data Frame

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("sep", ",").options(header= "true", inferschema='true').option('escape','"').load("{0}".format(path))
```

**Step2:** Create a temporary table

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("Customer")
```

**Step3:** Checking whether temporary table is created using SQL query.

```
%sql show tables
```

**Step4:** View content of the table using SQL query.

```
%sql select * from Customer
```

[image]